# Nested Http Requests and Pages

Tags: php, httprequest, php-curl

I am trying get retrieve some information from an API I received. I was able to make a call and get the info that was required but had to make separate HTTP calls and I am sure there is a better way to do this.

this is the structure of the JSON string I receive when I make the first call.

```
"data": [{
    "1": "1",
    "2": 69766,
    "3": {
        "4": 4
    },
    "links": {
        "1": {
            "links": {
                "self": "https://localhost/69766/1"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "links": {
                "self": "https://localhost/69766/2"
            }
        }
}],
"links": {
    "self": "https://localhost/69766/",
    "first": "https://localhost/69766/?page[number]=0",
    "next": "https://localhost/69766/?page[number]=1"
}
```

After the first call, I want to get one information from the self-link and also go to the next page number.

Thanks in advance. I am using PHP and cURL

Specifically, I want to get 2,4 and 2 from the self-links.

Comment: If the API is returning you http endpoints to hit, how you do envision hitting them without making another http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am sure there is a better way to do this.

No there is not.

You have to decode into an associative array the JSON received in the response: supposing the string is in `$response`

```
$data = json_decode( $response, TRUE );
```

Then traverse `$data` in order to retrieve the URL you have to fetch and finally make a CURL request for each one.